# WAMP and Domain Admin Password

Tags: windows

I am trying to get WAMP to run on Windows 7 PC with Drupal as the website editor. We upload our website pages onto another ISP provider but my staff member thinks she needs WAMP. She runs WAMP as a localhost.

I am setting this configuration up for our staff member who wants to use Drupal and she believes she needs WAMP. I  know nothing about these programs. I am an Admin for our domain and I installed both Drupal and WAMP but whenever she tries to start WAMP, it asks for an Admin user and password. This admin being my admin name and my admin password which I am not at liberty to hand out. Why is it asking for an admin password?

Anyone know how to get around this request for the domain admin password?

Comment: You're a domain admin and you don't know how to track down permission issues using tools like `procmon`?

Comment: For testing changes, your developer needs an environment that matches the production environment as closely as possible. That will not be WAMP.

Answer (score 2):

WAMP is a AMP implementation, that is, [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), [PHP](http://php.net/) and [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).  Apache runs on a privileged port < 1024, which requires privilege elevation.  In addition, it's possible this software was installed to the `%PROGRAMFILES%` directory which also requires privilege elevation for write access.

Typically, these tools are used by developers.  [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) is a CMS that runs on PHP and MySQL.  Consider WAMP, or any other AMP implementation a dependency for Drupal.

You can remedy the situation make making this user a local administrator of her machine.  If this is not possible, she's out of luck.

There are alternatives to WAMP, but you could also leverage virtualization if this is for development.